# Estimating correlation between age and rank in a competition

Tags: regression, correlation

Every year, I collect a list of 10 annual participants for a certain competition, their finishing rank, and their age in years. These data were collected annually for 20 years.

How would I test whether there is a correlation between age (young or old) and doing well in a competition (ranking high)?

Comment: A good starting place is just looking at the correlation coefficient between age and rank. The test for correlation can give you a 95% confidence interval for the correlation. A value of 0 means age and rank are not correlated.

Comment: @AdamO What software would you recommend?

Comment: Anything. R, JMP, SAS, Excel, Stata, PSPP, or Python. Questions about software aren't on-topic here, though.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about correlation, than use Pearson's r. It is simple and easy to understand. **If the people each year are different that is.** And here is the crux. If they are the same (or oft the same) people, than you need to account for the fact that variation within subjects is smaller than the variation between subjects. To avoid violating the independence assumption and producing biased results, you can use repeated-measure correlation such as [rmcorr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmcorr/rmcorr.pdf) in R (also see [this article for a thorough explanation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5383908/))

Comment: It is easy to understand but so is Kendall's coefficient and it has some advantages of Pearson's r. For instance Kendall's T is distribution free under the Null while Pearson's r is not and Kendall's T measures a monotonic relationship while r measures the degree of linearity between X and Y. In addition for small sample sizes I would prefer the exact test of independence from Kendall's T over the asymptotic test with Pearson's r. In short: the fact that Pearson's r is simple doesn't mean it is the right choice.